# how to test a react hook that can have a ref of an html element passed to it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hooks-testing-library

I have a custom hook that can have an optional ref passed to it as a property of an object that the hook takes as an argument:

```
export const useShortcuts = ({ ref }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const trapper = new mousetrap(ref.current);
```

The code works but I am now trying to write tests for this using `react-testing-library` and the [@testing-library/react-hooks](https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library) library.

I am using `renderHook` from [@testing-library/react-hooks](https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library) but I don't know how to create the ref or mock the ref outside of a component.

```
  it('should create shortcuts with no ref', () => {
    const ref = ?????  // how do I do this

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useShortcuts({ ref }), {
      initialProps: true
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 9):

You can create refs with [`React.createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs)

`const ref = React.createRef()`

Full working example below

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'

const useShortcuts = ({ ref }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = 1
  }, [])
}


it('works', () => {
  const ref = React.createRef()

  const { result } = renderHook(() => useShortcuts({ ref }))
  expect(ref.current).toEqual(1)
})
```

Comment: Please have a look at this i am facing same problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73977384/the-module-factory-of-jest-mock-is-not-allowed-to-reference-any-out-of-scope

Answer (score 4):

A typesafe way to do this (since in TypeScript createRef returns a readonly object), would be to just ditch the `createRef` idea and just create an object with a `current` property:

```
it('should create shortcuts with no ref', () => {
  const ref = { current: undefined }

  const { result } = renderHook(() => useShortcuts({ ref }), {
    initialProps: true
  });
});
```

Or if you want to pass an element:

```js
const elem = document.createElement('div');
const ref = { current: elem };
```

The latter should suffice as a type for TypeScript if the hook is expecting:

```js
ref: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>
```